# Ember 2 runtime Router.map mystery

Tags: ember.js, routes, runtime

I have a specific case where I need to add Ember routes during the application run-time (Chrome extension).

I have access to the `App.Router.map()`, but the given callback does not load.
Is there an official way, or even a dirty hack, to add additional routes during the application's lifespan?

**Edit 1**:
It's now clear there's no 'official' way to plug into the routing service during runtime. 
If just someone found a reasonable clean way in (version ~2.3)...

Comment: Well, its definitely not easy. Why would you ever do that btw? Maybe checkout the [`ember-engines` addon](https://github.com/dgeb/ember-engines), they do something like that.

Comment: On the why: a Chrome extension injecting added functionality is imo best served by using the application native structure. Thanks for the link!

Comment: The router map method takes a callback that is called on initialization of the router, the method has no side effects after the router has initialized.  You would need to look into manipulating the already configured dsl map, check out https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.5.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js#L80 and https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.5.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/dsl.js

Comment: This framework seems quite over-engineered. I've been digging multiple layers deep, but obscurity maintains... No profit.